# Knowledge Article ID's When Published Articles Are Edited Without a New Version

Tags: knowledge

In Salesforce Knowledge, we maintain a formula field that gives the URL of the article. This formula detects the `PublishStatus` and only gives the URL when the article is published.

i.e., `mycompany.force.com/ViewArticle?id=kaAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

However, we have recently discovered that users are updating published Articles without creating a new version by unchecking the "Flag as a New Version" checkbox in the "Publish Article" box.

[image: The "Flag as a new Version" box is unchecked by the user.]

Doing this, we have learned, updates the ID of the `KnowledgeArticleVersion` and removes all trace of the prior published version ID.

For Example:

1. User creates an Article and publishes it. Salesforce creates a `KnowledgeArticleVersion` record with Version 1, say kaA00000000000**1**.
2. Later, the User comes back and clicks Edit on the article, and makes some edits.
3. The user now clicks Publish, unchecks the "Flag as a New Version" and clicks OK.
4. Salesforce creates a new `KnowledgeArticleVersion` that is still Version 1, but carries a new ID, say kaA00000000000**2**.

In this case, there is no trace of kaA00000000000**1**. Querying for it gives no rows:

> `select knowledgearticleid from knowledgearticleversion where id = 'kaA000000000001' and publishstatus = 'archived'`

This gives no results for any of the valid `PublishStatus` values of `archived`, `online`, or `draft`.

On our Community, we have a process in the VF page that translates old ID's coming in via URL parameter to current published ID's, in case there are old blog posts, case comments, etc. floating out there.

So I need to trap that old ID somehow, but I understand that I can't create triggers on Knowledge objects.

Does anyone have any best practices for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Each time new version is published, a new Id of KnowledgeArticleVersion is created...so it's not safe to use this....instead that use KnowledgeArticleId field it would always redirect user to correct version.. something like this: mycompany.force.com/ViewArticle?id=kA1D00000001PQ6KAM

Comment: I'm aware and have custom code on the Community that does a translation. So any `KnowledgeArticleVersion` passed in via parameter will be translated to the newest version. However, I can't determine the right way to trap the ID when the published Article is updated without a new Version.